# Volvo V70 headlight is dim with a purple hue

Tags: headlight, volvo, parts, v70

My 2014 Volvo V70 D4 started having issues with the headlights. On the right side, the low beam (and also high beam, same device) are at perhaps 70% effect and have a noticeable purple tint.

I also noticed that on the left side, the orange side light (same enclosure, but to the left of the blinker) is not lit at all. I do not know whether this is a LED or incandescent bulb.

- Do I need to replace the entire enclosure, or can I replace just the broken lamps? (Is the low/high beam lamp even replaceable? I was of the impression that it's the kind that "never burns out", but was evidently mistaken.)
- Must I have it done at a garage, or can I buy parts off the Internet? I know that the lamp assembly can be unplugged and removed entirely in an extremely simple fashion, but that is only the first step.

Edit: I am in Denmark.

[image: Car seen from the front]

Edit: Thank you, car, I know.

[image: dashboard warning]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would agree it looks like your headlight is going out.

Volvo no longer sells the V70 here in the States (we have the XC70, but not a V70 in 2014, anyway). With that said, the other Volvo models use an H7 main headlight and an H9 for high beams (please check with the store for your particular application **UPDATE** - Per the OP's answer, the bulb is actually a **D1S**). These are completely user replaceable, and most of the time is an easy task. These are considered a composite headlamp system which means there are several parts to it. So, no, you shouldn't have to take these into a shop to get it fixed.

With that said, if you plan on changing these out yourself, ensure you use some type of gloves when you replace them. Whether it's nitrile or cotton gloves, you want to ensure you keep the oil from your fingers off of the bulb, as this will shorten the life of the bulb dramatically (we're talking weeks instead of years). Also, it's a VERY good idea to replace your bulbs in pairs. It is not very unusual for one bulb to burn out, to be followed in short order by the other side. Along this note, when you replace them together, this ensures both sides to be of the same luminance, which makes it so you don't see weird things on the road at night (it can shine weirdly).

Comment: It looks like you got the bulb model wrong, per the OP's answer below.  You might consider editing that.

Answer (score 3):

I have accepted Paulster2's answer to give credit. This answer is to provide further context.

It turns out that the bulb is not an H4 or H7, but something that is called a **D1S** which is not exactly cheap, but can certainly be replaced without replacing the entire headlight enclosure. There's enough of a base on the bulb that I don't think Paulster2's recommendation to wear gloves is critical.

[image: example of a D1S Bulb]
[image: headlight assembly removed]

On a modern Volvo, [headlight bulb replacement is extremely accessible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9YwChspUiw). I'm sure lots of people would love to see other manufacturers doing the same.

Comment: Your car is equipped with Xenon headlights, that is why your headlight module looks nothing like a simple H4 or H7 bulb. You are lucky that the light is user replaceable at all since many car manufacturers send you to the dealer for this job.

Comment: Well yeah, that was my initial expectation, until I asked. :-)